# Translate strings in APK GPlay

Tags: java, android, localization, google-play

Long trying to understand what's wrong.
Recently, for all my applications, Google Play Dev Console began to give advice: Translate strings in your APK into Russian.
But I have in all projects translation of apk stings:
/values-ru/strings.xml.
I tried and ru-rRU, but it did not help me.
By the number of all the lines from the standard language (English) are the same in Russian. On devices everything works as it should be.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `value-ru`? Not `values-ru`?

Comment: Sorry values-ru
I do everything as in manuals, Earlier Google did not issue such advice.
On devices everything works as it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response from google support:
I'm sorry to hear you are getting a message to include Russian in your APK. From what I can see in our systems, you do have the values-ru/strings.xml file as you mention. As a result you should be fine to ignore this. I will pass on the information from this issue to our technical team as well.

Answer (score 0):

By default you've already had a folder `../res/values/` with a string-resources file `string.xml`.

To add a locale resources please create a new folder `../res/values-ru/`.

Copy your default `string.xml` file into this folder and translate all texts if necessary.

Enjoy)

P.s. to see a proper file-tree structure in the Android Studio, switch a project view from the *Android* to the *Project* (upper left corner, jsut below the menu).